# Using reduce mul to return 1 instead of None on blank list

Tags: python, list, reduce

I'm trying to return 1 instead of None when I pass an empty list through `reduce(mul, a)`. My code:

```
from operator import mul
def product_list(a):
    for b in a:
        b = reduce(mul, a)
        if b == None:
            return 1
        return b

print product_list([])
```

No matter where I place the if statement to catch for a blank list, I still receive None as output. I am still learning basics, but this makes no sense to me. I've even tried

```
from operator import mul
def product_list(a):
    if a == None:
        return 1
    else:
        for b in a:
            b = reduce(mul, a)
            if b == None or a == None:
                return 1
            return b

print product_list([])
```

just to see if it would catch the None and return 1. Does reduce() not act the way I think that it does, or is there an obvious mistake in my code that prohibits returning 1 and forces a return of None?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `a` is an empty list, your function doesn't return anything, and the default return value is `None`.

Test for the empty list at the top:

```
if not a:
    return 1
```

In your second function you only test for `if a == None`, but an empty list `[]` is never equal to `None`. Note that the idiomatic way to test for `None` is using the `is` object identity test instead:

```
if a is None:
```

By testing for `not a` instead, you catch both the case where `a` is an empty list *and* a being `None`.

Your code otherwise makes little sense. You loop over `a` but return and exit the function in the first iteration:

```
for b in a:
    b = reduce(mul, a)
    if b == None:
        return 1
    return b  # exit the function here, having only looked at the first element in `a`.
```

However, I had to fix the indentation in your post and may have misunderstood the indentation of those `return` statements, in which case you would get a `NameError` instead when passing in an empty list.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, that did work, and I feel dumb it was that simple. I am still running through tutorials on python, so that explains why it doesn't make sense to do this. But thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a third value to `reduce`, which is used as a starter value.

```
In [6]: reduce(mul, [], 1)
Out[6]: 1
```

This is the best way to deal with an empty list. The case `None` should really be dealt with elsewhere, because it's a different kind of error: it's nothing wrong with the semantics of the program, it's because someone else has given you bad data. You should catch that explicitly, as e.g.

```
if not isinstance(..., collections.Iterable):
   # do something
```

Of course, `reduce` will raise an error if you pass it something not iterable, and that may suffice for you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you're not passing an empty list to reduce as you say.  Try it:

```
>>> reduce(operator.mul, [])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

I think that perhaps you don't understand the function `reduce`.  We can't hold it against you though -- it's not used much in python code.

Perhaps you wanted to define a function like this:

```
from operator import mul
def product_list(a):
    try:
        return reduce(mul,a)
    except TypeError:
        return 1
```

Now you can try it:

```
print product_list([1,2,3,4]) #24
print product_list([])  #1
```

Comment: Note that you could "look before you leap" (LBYL):  `if a: return reduce(mul,a); else return 1`, but why bother when it's "easier to ask forgiveness than permission" (EAFP)

Comment: I think LBYL is preferable here over EAFP. Suppose the client defines a `Widget` class and accidentally passes an instance to `product_list`. We would prefer that `product_list` raise a `TypeError`, since it doesn't make sense to get the product of a Widget. But the try-except code will happily return 1, fooling the client into thinking the code works.

Comment: @Kevin -- It's a good argument, but I think you could make virtually the same argument for almost any `try-except` code you could write anywhere.  The benefit of EAFP is that you could pass a generator into this function and it will work.  If you LBYL, then you'd need to look for generators as well as `bool(genertor)` seems to always give `True`.  The point is that you need to be careful what you're passing to your function no matter how you code it.  Alternatively, you could look at `a` inside `except` and `raise` if you got something that isn't sequence like.

Comment: I claim you're both wrong (mwa ha ha =), because there are two _different_ errors that could be raised: `ArgumentError` if you pass a non-iterable to `reduce`, and `TypeError` if you pass an empty iterable without an initial value. @mgilson is talking about the benefits of ignoring the latter, and Kevin the price of ignoring the former.

Comment: @katrielalex -- I believe Kevin was talking about the price of allowing the former to pass by simply returning 1.  However, if `reduce` does in fact raise a different error if it gets a non-iterable object (which I believe you), then my answer has no problem with that (though, I agree, yours is better *if* the objects involved can be multiplied by 1 which seems to be a pretty safe assumption -- Otherwise 1 isn't a very good default value).

Answer (score 0):

```
if a is None or len(a) == 0:
    return 1
```

Check the empty list condition as above.